# can mushroom improve your memory?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Mushrooms have several benefits. One of these is psychological. Can mushroom improve human memory?

Comment: This question is too broad - there are many, many species of mushroom (fungi).

Answer (score -1):

Mushrooms contain psilocybin, which gets converted into psilocin. These act on serotonin receptors, which may play a role in memory. (Edits coming later)

Comment: *Magic* mushrooms contain psilocin and psylocibin (*Psylocibe cubensis*, among others). By far not all of them do; they're an exception to the rule really.

Comment: I guess I assumed he was talking about magic mushrooms. Why would mushrooms of the normal edible variety improve memory any more than any other nutritious food?